# Retrofit 2 error in Json parsing

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I want to send a post response with no parameters on my url. However the response I am getting is this

```
[Lcom.example.c4u015.retrotestapp.Questions;@97ddd71
```

but the actual response is this

```
 {
"MemberDays": "[{"Dt":"02/19/2016","AM":"0","AMS":"1","NS":"0","NSS":"0","PM":"1","PMS":"0","SB":"0","DS":"0","Note":""},{"Dt":"02/25/2016","AM":"0","AMS":"0","NS":"0","NSS":"0","PM":"0","PMS":"0","SB":"0","DS":"0","Note":""}]"
"Message": ""
"Status": "0"
}
```

This is my code.

```
   Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.99:82/MembersWS.svc/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        gitAPI stackOverflowAPI = retrofit.create(gitAPI.class);

        Call<Questions[]> call = stackOverflowAPI.loadQuestions();

         call.enqueue(new Callback<Questions[]>() {
             @Override
             public void onResponse(Response<Questions[]> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                 if (response.isSuccess()) {
                     Questions[] user = response.body();
                     Log.e("parsed"," on response");
                     Log.e("response", response.body().toString()+" "+response.raw().toString());
                 } else {
                     int statusCode = response.code();
Log.e("status",""+statusCode);
                     // handle request errors yourself
                     ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                 }
                 pd.dismiss();


             }

             @Override
             public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                 pd.dismiss();
                 Log.e("error", t.getLocalizedMessage());
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         });
```

And this is the interface I have used

```
public interface gitAPI {
    @POST("GetMemberAvailability/MBR0011581")
    Call<Questions[]> loadQuestions();
}
```

Comment: `response.body.toString()` should be something like `[Lcom.example.c4u015.retrotestapp.Questions;@97ddd71`. What is the problem? or what is the desired effect?

Comment: how to get the raw response json i am getting?

Comment: you are printing the object it which is what you see, what will be the output of `Log.i("response",user[0].getXXX());` where XXX is any getter method for class `Questions`

Comment: the object user is not getting the getters of question class. could not resolve

Comment: did you use the `[]` ?? like i told you `user[0].get...`?

Comment: yeah thanks it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are printing the output of the `toString()` which is **object id** in this case, and it's value is waht you see `[Lcom.example.c4u015.retrotestapp.Questions;@97ddd71`

your response is an Array of type Question, so to print the output you will have to iterate over the array's items and call getters , ex:

`user[0].getXXX();` where XXX is any getter method for class Questions

or you can use a `for loop` or other process you wish